# Aligning mixed form input types with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am stuck hard on a project. It requires a form, and aligning the text input boxes/radio buttons/etc in a straight line down the page. I have achieved this with the text input boxes no problem, but I can't get the rows with radio buttons, checkboxes, or textareas to behave. Code is:

HTML:

```
<div class="containdiv">
    <label>Phone <img src="circle.gif" /></label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="4" size="4">
    <input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="4" size="4">
    <input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="4" size="4">
</div>

<div class="containdiv">
    <label>Preferred Contact <img src="circle.gif" /></label>
    <div class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="email" value="email">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="radio" name="phone" value="phone">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: right;
}

input, select, span.radio, textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
    float: left;
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the div breaks lines. Is using this divs is necessary?

Comment: Probably not? I can try that without it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure HTML and CSS example. The only external resource is a google font I added to improve the text. It is a little complex but play around with it.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Open Sans;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.text-center {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
hr {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5px 10%;
}
form {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
form .form-group {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
form .form-group label,
form .form-group .form-control {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
form .form-group > label {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
form .form-group div.form-control {
  padding: 0;
}
form .form-group .checkbox,
form .form-group .btn {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
form .form-group .form-control label {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
form .form-group .form-control label.radio-inline {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- title -->
<h1 class="text-center">Form</h1>
<hr>

<form>
  
  <!-- email -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text">
  </div>

  <!-- who are you -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Who you are</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
  </div>

  <!-- favorite number -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Favorite number</label>
    <select class="form-control">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <!-- how many pizzas -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>How many pizzas</label>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="pizzas" value="male">1</label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="pizzas" value="female">2</label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="pizzas" value="female">3</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- where did you hear about us -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Where did you hear about us</label>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="referral" value="male">The internet</label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="referral" value="female">From a friend</label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="referral" value="female">Other</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- send me updates -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">Send me updates</div>
  </div>

  <!-- submit -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So your markup is not valid and is impossible to follow so lets start over and help you out.

You want your elements in a form in a tabular arrangement, so lets use a table. You have 3 inputs for 1 phone number, why not just use 1?

This is a form so we need a form tag:

```
<form>
</form>
```

In the form lets add a table with 2 lines.

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Now lets put our fields in the table.

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Preferred Contact</td>
            <td>Phone <input type="radio" name="preferred"></td>
            <td>Email <input type="radio" name="preferred"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoQWEW)

I highly suggest you read: [W3Schools Forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), [W3Schools Tables](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Comment: I think Michael isn't familiar with forms, but that was not the question. The question was: aligning the text input boxes/radio buttons/etc in a straight line down the page. Your answer focuses more the form part then aligning everything.

Comment: The solution to that is a table.

Comment: Look at Michael's code. It might give you a better idea of what he is going for.

Comment: I tried  the table solution, it didn't work. Wait, I forgot to use colspan, that might have been the issue.

Comment: @Michael Colspan is just to make your phone input box take up 2 table cells, if you would like to have multiple boxes just add more TD's to that row with each box.

Comment: For the record, tables worked perfectly this time around. For the benefit of others, what I was doing wrong before seemed to be keeping the label tags. Once I dropped those, everything fell into place.

Comment: Labels work fine for me: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoQWEW). Make sure to accept my answer if it helped you..

Answer (score -1):

@christian i get ur point

## i think this one would help

Create the form in html and style it with css in the following way...
Use labels to write the names next to the text boxes
Like: Username

Now style it and try tu arrange it in css by targeting the label and the input in the following way:

label {
margin : 5px 15px;
And whatever you want to style
}
Input
{
margin:5px 0px 10px 150px;
Hint....the 150px is the one that will push all the textboxes to start on 150px of the page soh its up to you to place it any where you want on the page by changing the left margin to whatever you want which is currently the 150px
}

Comment: This is a great example of what not to do. Html will not show more then one space between words/tags for good reason. What Thami is suggesting is you force html (using `&nbsp`) to align everything using spaces. This is like trying to center a title in Microsoft word using spaces rather the center aligning it.